# Redid 3.0 cluster data

Tags: hash, redis, cluster-computing

I have two questions about redid 3.0 cluster.

1. What are hash slots and what exactly is their purpose?
2. Do nodes in the redid cluster share the same data I.e, the data in every node is the same just like nodes (master-master) in a galera cluster with share the same data?

Answer (score 0):

1. The hash slots are how the keys are devided into separate nodes of the cluster, so one node will have inside a number of those slots. There are maximum 16384 slots so theoretically you should not have more than 16384 nodes in a cluster because they would not get anything to store. Practically a hash slot is a set of keys that are going to be found on a single node.
2. Every node will store different part of the data and the client will get routed to the node that has the desired key. Once the cluster is stable (so you are not adding or removing nodes) one hash slot will always be inside the same node so the client can remember the relation between keys and nodes. Also every node of the cluster can have its own master-slave replication.

More details here:
http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

Comment: So one node can have many hash slots, and each hash slots can store multiple keys? Also, does the hash slot store the keys and the mapping values too, or the values are stored somewhere else?

Comment: Yes one node can have many hash slots, there is a mapping table between hash slots and nodes kept on every node (look for mapping keyword in the cluster-spec link). Yes, each hash slot can contain multiple keys, the base algorithm being: HASH_SLOT = CRC16(key) mod 16384, but there are some exceptions  (look for the hash tag in the cluster-spec link). I couldn't find anything in the documentation if the node keeps some mapping between his hash slot and his keys or if they are computed everytime.

Comment: Thanks Liviu. I did read the documentation-spec but I thought the explanation was vague. That is the reason I asked these questions to get a more clear understanding.